# Suppressing broadcast traffic in honeyd logs?

Tags: honeypot

I'm trying to set up a honeyd system. How can I suppress the broadcast traffic seen by the outside interface, preferably without needing to resort to syslog filters?

User subnet 192.168.20.0/24, default route 192.168.20.1
HoneyD subnet 192.168.25.0/24. The IP used to reach here is 192.168.20.254.

The router has a static route entry for 192.168.25.0/24 via 192.168.20.254.

Everything works as I would expect except for getting all the traffic bound for 192.168.20.255 in my logs.

This is mostly from NETBIOS traffic but it happens elsewhere as well.

Note - I did review [Honeyd: log grows too fast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25717/honeyd-log-grows-too-fast). Still seems there should be a way to address this without needing to restructure my network. I really do want the gateway to be sitting in a subnet that will be picking up real traffic.

Comment: Filter packets at firewall?